# Error when compiling a Cocos2d-x project on Android platform

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The declared package "org.cocos2dx.lib" does not match the expected package "src.org.cocos2dx.lib"    Cocos2dxMusic.java    /java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib    line 24    Java Problem

Someone said that cocos2d-x 2.0.3 has a bug that will not create cocos2dx.lib.
Anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: please give some more details on what you want to do ??

Comment: you can see this  http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started    in this you will nicely guided on how you could select your libraries of cocos2dX